# Enter psql without password requirement for user postgres

Tags: postgresql, password

I have set `PGPASSWORD` in my `.bashrc`:

```
export PGPASSWORD=mypass
```

Now i can enter into psql with :

```
psql -u postgres
```

Set nopasswd in `/etc/sudoers`

```
user  ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/su - postgres
```

Then i toggle to user postgres from my normal user without password requirement.

su - postgres

After i enter into bash console with user `postgres` ,to type `psql`

```
psql 
Password for user postgres:
```

It need password authentication again,how can enter the psql console without password in this case?

Comment: If you want the OS user named postgres to use PGPASSWORD, then you need to set it in that user's .bashrc.  Setting it in your .bashrc isn't effective for a different user.  The whole things seems rather misguided though, why do you want to use sudo once you've already set it up so that you don't need to use it?

Comment: Why use `sudo` at all? Can't you just use `psql -U postgres`?